# error: expected expression before 'if'

Tags: c

Trying to make a GCD program using Euclid's Method, but I keep getting this error:

> error: expected expression before 'if'

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 30, b = 42;

    while(a!=b) (
        if(b>a) {
            b=b-a
        }
        else(a>b) {
            a=a-b
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information - for example, the error message.

Comment: Yeah, `The If Error`. It's the worst.

Comment: @rghome The error message is in the title, but should be in the body as well :)

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong. You need braces after the while and you need another if after the else.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot to put semicolons (;) and parenthesis ({}) in your code at appropriate place, also `else` does not take any condition so you need to use `else if` condition.

Here is your modified code.

```
int main() 
{
    int a = 30, b = 42;
    while(a!=b)
    {
        if(b>a) 
        {
            b=b-a;
        }
        else  if(a>b)
        {
            a=a-b;
        }
    }
}
```